# Spring MVC Jboss IE 11, Who is responsible for setting the content type

Tags: java, spring-mvc, internet-explorer, jboss, mime

I have a spring MVC application that refers to a js library called fancytree which has js files and css files. The css file inside fancytree refers to a gif image.

Now the application is deployed on a JBoss server. When trying to access the gif image, IE 11 gets a 200 but the content type is image/png.

However on chrome it is image/webp.

I tried

1) Setting the mime mappings in web.xml but that dint work

```
  <mime-mapping>
      <extension>gif</extension>
      <mime-type>image/gif</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>

 <mime-mapping>
      <extension>html</extension>
      <mime-type>text/html</mime-type>
 </mime-mapping>
```

2) Adding a servlet customizer

```
@Component
public class ServletCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer      {

@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    MimeMappings mappings = new MimeMappings(MimeMappings.DEFAULT);
    mappings.add("gif","image/gif");
    container.setMimeMappings(mappings);
}
}
```

3) Changing MvcConfiguration

```
@Override
   public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
  configurer.favorPathExtension(false).
          favorParameter(true).
          parameterName("mediaType").
          ignoreAcceptHeader(true).
          useJaf(false).
          defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
          mediaType("xml", MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).
          mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).
          mediaType("gif", MediaType.IMAGE_GIF).
          mediaType("png", MediaType.IMAGE_PNG);
}
```

4) Setting the global mime mappings in JBoss standalone.xml

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:2.2" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
        <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
        <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="false">
            <alias name="localhost"/>
            <alias name="example.com"/>
        </virtual-server>
        <configuration>
            <mime-mapping name="gif" value="image/gif" />
            <mime-mapping name="png" value="image/png" />
            <mime-mapping name="html" value="text/html" />
        </configuration>
</subsystem>
```

All of the above dint work.

My question is who is responsible for setting the MIME types, is it the browser or the web server. If the web server is responsible what am I doing wrong when trying to set the mime types, that in IE 11 it always comes back with a content-type image/png

Comment: Hi, it sounds like the server-side code is using UserAgent sniffing. However... MSIE browsers don't support webp formats so what you see would be expected. You could use the Emulation tab of IE dev tools to select a different UAS to send in the request header, (and find out which IE Emulation mode you are currently using)

Comment: Typically you may be developing on localhost. Use the File>Properties menu in IE to find out if localhost is mapped to your IE INtranet zone, then use the Emulation tab of dev tools to find out which IE emulation (and UAS) IE is using in that zone and how it was established...typically see the Security tab of Internet Options>Intranet Sites>Advanced button>remove localhost from the list so you dev environment will map to the Internet zone and use an 'Edge' emulation mode and send an Agnostic UAS string in the header...the server will still send webp for userAgents that support that format.